# Get a refined list using Linq

Tags: c#, linq, list, xaml, visual-studio-2012

I have a class `DataGroups` defined as follows:

```
 public DataGroups(String uniqueId, String title, String subtitle, String imagePath, String description)
```

In my C# code of my Windows 8 app, I use this code to load the on the XAML page

```
  protected override void LoadState(Object navigationParameter, Dictionary<String, Object> pageState)
        {

            var DataGroups = DataSource.GetGroups((String)navigationParameter);
            this.DefaultViewModel["DGroups"] = DataGroups;
        }
```

`GetGroups` is defined as follows

```
 private ObservableCollection<DataGroups> _allGroups = new ObservableCollection<DataGroups>();
        public ObservableCollection<DataGroups> AllGroups
        {
            get { return this._allGroups; }
        }
    public static IEnumerable<DataGroups> GetGroups(string uniqueId)
        {
            if (!uniqueId.Equals("AllGroups")) throw new ArgumentException("Only 'AllGroups' is supported as a collection of groups");

            return _DataSource.AllGroups;
        }
```

This returns the full list of Data Groups.

How do I refine a function, to get only the list of data groups with a specific `Title` to display on the XAML page, using Linq?

Return the list of Data groups where the `Title` matches a defined value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public List<DataGroups> GetDataGroupsByName(string name) {
     return _allGroups.Where(x => x.Title == name);
}
```

Comment: would this go in the `GetGroups`?

Comment: @Tester: I have edited my post. I noticed you're using `SectorGroups` sometimes without ever explaining the connection between `SectorGroups` and `DataGroups`.

Comment: Sorry see above, all should be `DataGroups`

Comment: In that case my example should work just fine, assuming your `DataGroups` object exposes a public property.